# How to stop content of tab flash randomly when switch between tabs in Notebook of tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

After multiple tabs built in ttk.Notebook, content of tab will flash occasionally when switching between tabs.

Here's a simple code to show it. Run this script, then click `TAB 1`, `TAB 2` again and again, you will find, somethime or most of time, content of tab will flash, sometime not.

My question is 'Is it possible, no flash on content of tab when switching between tabs ?'

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

font = ('Courier New', 16)

notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack()

frame1 = Frame(notebook)
frame2 = Frame(notebook)

notebook.add(frame1, text='TAB 1')
notebook.add(frame2, text='TAB 2')

for i in range(10):
    label = Label(frame1, text=f"Label {i}", width=40, height=1, font=font)
    label.pack()
    entry = Entry(frame1, width=40, font=font)
    entry.pack()
    label = Label(frame2, text=f"Label {i}", width=40, height=1, font=font)
    label.pack()
    entry = Entry(frame2, width=40, font=font)
    entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm 2 years late, but I just recently experienced the flickering issue myself when switching tabs.

A solution I discovered is instead of attaching the frames to notebook you have to attach it to the parent of the notebook, e.g.,

From

```
frame1 = Frame(notebook)
frame2 = Frame(notebook)
```

To

```
frame1 = Frame(root)
frame2 = Frame(root)
```

Then weirdly the flickering disappeared.

Comment: It looks like that it work fine. Do you know why or the difference between them ?

Comment: @JasonYang I'm not 100% sure, but it must be something to do with widgets getting redrawn every time a tab changes. Although in Linux the flicker does seem less prominent.

Comment: When I switched to using `root` I found that the whole frame would stutter (or flicker) when I switched tabs, rather than just the page when using the `notebook` as the parent